# How to use Django's admin Boolean icons in a custom template?

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a django template that at one point displays a boolean variable. However, I want to display an icon instead of the words "True" or "False". I know the Django Admin does this. I'm trying to avoid having to use something like this everytime I do it:

```
{% if variable %} True Icon HTML {% else %} False Icon HTML {% endif %}
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make one template file (for example called `boolean_icon.html`) with this content:

```
{% if myvar==True %}
  True Icon HTML
{% else %}
  False Icon HTML
{% endif %}
```

and in your main templates use:

```
{% include 'boolean_icon.html' with myvar=boolean_variable_name %}
```

it is potentially the same thing, except we remove the need to repeat code over and over again, and if you ever decided to change the icons, or color, or whatever, you only need to change it at one spot.

Comment: One more question. How does the Django admin do this? I don't even know where to begin looking for this in Django's source code.

Comment: Can't really help you there, never messed with the django admin app

Comment: @ChrisM you can get Django Admin's icons with `{% static 'admin/img/icon-yes.svg' %}` or `{% static 'admin/img/icon-no.svg' %}`